# Android LIstView Adapter delete file and view on item click?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-adapter

I have an issue with my code below. I need the user to be able to click the item in the list and have a menu pop up that asks if they would like to either load or delete the file. I am having no problem getting the file loaded but I cannot get the delete funciton to work. Right now I need the user to be able to click the item and have the file deleted along with the view on the list. I have tried everything and I cannot get the file deleted from the sd card or have the view deleted from the listview or the view. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public class loadActivity : Activity,ListView.IOnItemClickListener
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.loadhead);
        Button buttonBack = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnLoadHeadBack);
        buttonBack.Click += delegate {
            Finish ();
        };

        ListView listView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.headList);

        String loadData = myResources.saveLoadData;
        if (loadData == null || loadData == "")
            return;
        String[] splitData = loadData.Substring (0, loadData.Length - 1).Split ('\n');
        var Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, splitData);

        listView.Adapter = Adapter;
        listView.OnItemClickListener = this;



    }
        public void OnItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            //whatever you need it to do goes here.
            var fileName = parent.GetItemAtPosition(position);
            var sdCardPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
            var textPath = Path.Combine(sdCardPath, fileName.ToString());
            var load = new Intent (this, typeof(results));
            load.PutExtra("LoadData" , readFileSdcardFile(textPath));
        //  myResources.isLast = false;
        //  myResources.isLoadingNow = true; 
        //  myResources.songLyrics = ""; 
        //  StartActivity (load);
        parent.RemoveViewInLayout (view);  
        File.Delete (readFileSdcardFile(sdCardPath)); 






    }






    public String readFileSdcardFile(String path) {
        if (File.Exists (path)) {
            var str = File.ReadAllText (path);
            return str;
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are passing the **sdcard** path not **file path**

replace this line in **OnItemClick**

`File.Delete (readFileSdcardFile(sdCardPath))`;

to

```
File.Delete (readFileSdcardFile(textPath));
```

or

```
File.Delete ("file path");
```

Comment: are you try it?  File.Delete (textPath);

Comment: what you got in textPath ? path or empty string?

Comment: IT was an empty string.

Comment: are you got filename?

Comment: It gets the file name from a text file that it saves the names of the songs to. If I could even just make it so that the view is removed and the listview is updated that would help a lot.

Comment: var textPath = Syatem.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, fileName.ToString());
try it.
 are you get textPath using it?

Comment: Okay. I found out my problem. Your solution was correct. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the correct permissions on true in your manifest?

Like this one:  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Also, why do you try to delete your file by passing the content as parameter? You don't return a path, you return the content of your file.
The System.IO.Delete function takes the path of your file and deletes it. So just `File.Delete(sdCardPath)` should be enough IF your file path is correct.

Comment: I do have the permissions set correctly. I know the path is correct because I use the same code to load the files correctly but I cannot get it to delete the file, the view or anything. I tried what you said and it still did not work. the files and everything are still there